# Is there any way to make the iPad simulator bigger?

Tags: ipad, simulator

It kind of annoys me how small the iPad simulator is... Some apps I have in mind I have difficulty testing because of the small size of the iPad simulator. Is there anyway to make it larger than it currently is?

Comment: Menu Bar: Window -> Scale -> 100%: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: +1, I'd like to know the answer too!

Maybe a clue: On a 15" MBP plugged to a 1920x1200 screen, the iPad sim seems to display at half the native iPad resolution, so it looks quite small. However, on a Mac Mini plugged to the same screen, the ratio is now 1:1, so the sim is much bigger and nicer to look at...
My guess is that the sim total size is limited by the resolution of the smallest screen on your system! I don't know if there's any way to change that...

Comment: @chpwn Exactly!!! Thanks!!! I was wondering how to do that!

Comment: If you are using Xcode? If so, there's a section where you click the blue "I" icon and then under the "Build" tab you would scroll down below to Deployment and in there on the side is "Targeted Device Family" to the right of this click "iPhone" then change this to "iPhone/iPad" then your sim will be full screen of the entire iPad.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Menu Bar: Window->scale as shown in comments by chpwn.

Answer (score 0):

You can always zoom the screen in.  Usually something like control-scroll but check your mouse or trackpad system preferences.  command-option-backslash toggles antialiasing if you need to see magnified pixels when zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

in iPhone Simulater menu bar go to
window > scale > 100%

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, you can create a keyboard shortcut to make it easier:

- goto System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts
- click small "+" at bottom of list
- drop down Application list and scroll to bottom, choose Other
- browse to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications  (at least on my machine)
- choose iOS Simulator
- for Menu Title enter "100%" without the quotes
- for Keyboard Shortcut, press your shortcut key e.g. Cmd-F  ('F'ull screen)
- click Add and you're done
- close and restart the simulator and press Cmd-F

HTH - DF

Answer (score 0):

press command 1, Command 2, or, Command 3. it will change the screen size. Easy fix!